# Analizar XML con namespaces peculiares

Tags: php, xml

He estado desarrollando desde 0 un formulario web para poder hacer una búsqueda de archivos.

Para ello necesito validar cierta información metiéndome en ficheros ZIP abriéndolos **sin descomprimirlos** y analizar su sintaxis comparando valores según lo que ingresen.

El problema es que estos XML son muy peculiares y usan esta cosa llamada [XML namespaces](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp).

Estoy usando SimpleXML con PHP para poder leer estos datos pero no encuentro la forma de poder acceder a los elementos.

- Primero: porque no sé PHP y lo estoy aprendiendo.
- Segundo: porque nunca he hecho algo relacionado de este tipo, alguna vez usé CSV así que ando nuevo en esto.

Esto es lo que tengo hecho en **PHP**:

```
<?php
if (file_exists($file))
{
    $zip = new ZipArchive;
    if ($zip->open($file)) {  
        $file_found = $zip->getFromName(($code.'.xml'));
        $xml = simplexml_load_file($file_found);
        $name = $xml->{'cac:AccountingCustomerParty'}->{'cac:Party'}->{'cac:PartyIdentification'}->{'cbc:ID'};
        echo $name;
        $zip->close();
    } else {
        echo('Unable to open zip.');
    }
} else {
    echo('File not found.');
}
```

Y este es el archivo **XML**:

En este caso, solo quiero extraer lo que está en `<cbc:ID></cbc:ID>`:

```
<cac:AccountingCustomerParty>
    <cac:Party>
        <cac:PartyIdentification>
            <cbc:ID schemeID="6" schemeName="Documento de Identidad" schemeAgencyName="PE:SUNAT" schemeURI="urn:sssss:6">00000000011</cbc:ID>
        </cac:PartyIdentification>
        <cac:PartyName>
            <cbc:Name><![CDATA[MUNICIPALIDAD]]></cbc:Name>
        </cac:PartyName>
        <cac:PartyTaxScheme>
            <cbc:RegistrationName><![CDATA[MUNICIPALIDAD]]></cbc:RegistrationName>
            <cbc:CompanyID schemeID="6" schemeName="SUNAT:Identificador de Documento de Identidad" schemeAgencyName="PE:SUNAT" schemeURI="urn:sssss:6">00000000011</cbc:CompanyID>
            <cac:TaxScheme>
                <cbc:ID schemeID="6" schemeName="SUNAT:Identificador de Documento de Identidad" schemeAgencyName="PE:SUNAT" schemeURI="urn:sssss:6">00000000011</cbc:ID>
            </cac:TaxScheme>
        </cac:PartyTaxScheme>
        <cac:PartyLegalEntity>
            <cbc:RegistrationName><![CDATA[MUNICIPALIDAD]]></cbc:RegistrationName>
            <cac:RegistrationAddress>
                <cac:AddressLine>
                    <cbc:Line><![CDATA[PZA. PLAZA DE ARMAS]]></cbc:Line>
                </cac:AddressLine>
                <cac:Country>
                    <cbc:IdentificationCode listID="ISO 3166-1" listAgencyName="United Nations Economic Commission for Europe" listName="Country">PE</cbc:IdentificationCode>
                </cac:Country>
            </cac:RegistrationAddress>
        </cac:PartyLegalEntity>
    </cac:Party>
</cac:AccountingCustomerParty>
```

Pero `echo $xml;` no escribe nada, además el programa no entrega ninguna salida, así que errores no han salido.

Quisiera saber cómo acceder a los elementos

Gracias por su tiempo.

Comment: Hola, Egon. Añade, por favor, el XML de ejemplo en código en lugar de imagen para poder ayudarte, sino, tendremos que usar un ejemplo genérico y con un namespace distinto y distintos niveles de etiqueta. Saludos.

Comment: No nos vale una captura, preferiríamos que lo compartieses en el código copiando/pegando o bien que compartieras el archivo ZIP en algún servicio como Drive, Mega, etc. Nos sería de gran ayuda un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) para poder reproducir tu problema y así poder ayudarte a resolverlo.

Comment: @OscarGarcia ya modifique la pregunta, gracias

Comment: Disculpa, he tenido mucha carga de trabajo. Esta noche le echo un vistazo.

Comment: Redacté una respuesta tras reproducir tu problema. Espero que te haya sido de ayuda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estás cometiendo varios errores.

- Estás obteniendo el contenido del archivo como cadena de caracteres en `$file_found` y luego intentas abrir un archivo con ese nombre en `ZipArchive::getFromName()`. Obviamente ese no es el nombre de archivo.
- Estás analizando un XML que es incorrecto porque no estás definiendo correctamente los espacios de nombre. Por este motivo simplexml te lanzará multitud de mensajes de advertencia. Esos mensajes de advertencia no los ves si no activas las opciones de desarrollo en tu servidor web.
- Estás intentando acceder al elemento raíz como si fuera un hijo de éste. El elemento `<cac:AccountingCustomerParty>` ya es elemento raíz, por lo que no tienes que descender por él para obtener la información deseada.

### Apertura del archivo

Para solucionar el primer punto tienes dos opciones:

**Abrir el archivo usando la [envoltura `zip://`](https://www.php.net/wrappers.compression):**

```
$xml = @simplexml_load_file('zip://'. $file .'#'. $code .'.xml');
```

**Cargando el contenido del archivo en memoria:**

```
$contenido = $zip->getFromName(($code.'.xml'));
$xml = @simplexml_load_string($contenido);
```

Ambas formas son equivalentes, aunque es preferible usar la primera para evitar mantener el contenido de un archivo XML en memoria tras su análisis y, además, te ahorras la apertura y tratamiento de un archivo ZIP.

Además, como te comenté en el segundo punto, simplexml te lanzará multitud de mensajes de advertencia al analizar tu XML aunque finalmente lo cargue sin problemas. Para evitar la salida de esos mensajes al registro de error del servidor web o que aparezcan en pantalla, he usado el prefijo `@` para ocultar dichos mensajes pero, posteriormente, compruebo que no devuelve `false` (error cargando el archivo XML).

### Acceso a la información

Como he dicho anteriormente, el nodo raíz ya es `<cac:AccountingCustomerParty>`, por lo que para acceder al dato que deseas debes usar:

```
    $name = $xml->{'cac:Party'}->{'cac:PartyIdentification'}->{'cbc:ID'};
```

---

Tu código quedaría:

```
<?php
$file = 'archivo.zip';
$code = 'archivo';
if (file_exists($file)) {
    $xml = @simplexml_load_file('zip://'. $file .'#'. $code .'.xml');
    if ($xml === false) {
        die('Error abriendo el archivo XML dentro del ZIP');
    }
    $name = $xml->{'cac:Party'}->{'cac:PartyIdentification'}->{'cbc:ID'};
    echo $name, PHP_EOL;
} else {
    die('Archivo no encontrado');
}
```

He dejado el código con el que he reproducido tu problema en el siguiente repositorio de Github:

- https://github.com/ojgarciab/389788-stackoverflow-es

Comment: tengo una pregunta, que pasa si quiero acceder a una carpeta antes de hacer zip. Me explico, dentro de mi pagina web tengo el folder `data` en donde estan los archivos zip. A pesar de que intento de diferentes formas no encuentro forma de acceder al zip con lo que me haz puesto, tengo esto `'/dada/zip://'.$file.'#'.$code.'.xml'` pero al parecer no funciona por la envoltura `zip://`

Comment: Te he respondido en tu pregunta en inglés: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64038172/reading-nasty-xml-with-php/64040224#64040224](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64038172/reading-nasty-xml-with-php/64040224#64040224)